# How do I align a block of text into columns?

Tags: align

For instance, let's say I have the following block of code in a buffer:

```
pattern TTF_STYLE_NORMAL = #{const TTF_STYLE_NORMAL}
pattern TTF_STYLE_BOLD = #{const TTF_STYLE_BOLD}
pattern TTF_STYLE_ITALIC = #{const TTF_STYLE_ITALIC}
pattern TTF_STYLE_STRIKETHROUGH = #{const TTF_STYLE_STRIKETHROUGH}
```

I want to convert it into:

```
pattern TTF_STYLE_NORMAL        = #{const TTF_STYLE_NORMAL}
pattern TTF_STYLE_BOLD          = #{const TTF_STYLE_BOLD}
pattern TTF_STYLE_ITALIC        = #{const TTF_STYLE_ITALIC}
pattern TTF_STYLE_STRIKETHROUGH = #{const TTF_STYLE_STRIKETHROUGH}
```

I need some way of saying *align this block into columns divided by the `=` character*. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do the same thing with multiple delimiter characters, like splitting on a `->`.

How could I accomplish this?

If there's a minor mode for it - great! Code samples welcome also.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have googled a bit more before asking.

I can align the code by selecting it and applying `align-regexp` with an argument of `=`.

Feel free to give a potentially better and/or more detailed answer, I'll accept it.